# Selecting dates from two dataframes and creating a new dataframe in R

Tags: r, date, merge, dplyr, data.table

I would like to select the dates (in date B) that are closest to Date A and then create a new dataframe with these matches. There can be multiple rows for each ID (ie. multiple date combinations). I am using dplyr and data.table packages

```
dataframe A

ID  DATE A
3   15/05/06
5   14/11/05
8   25/11/08
1   16/12/10
1   5/01/12
1   24/07/14

dataframe B

ID  DATE B
3   12/12/05
3   17/04/06
5   25/07/05
5   26/09/05
5   1/12/05
8   12/09/08
8   13/11/08
8   23/12/08
8   31/03/09
1   26/11/10
1   12/08/11
1   12/11/11
1   14/03/14
1   8/08/14

Resultant dataframe:
ID  DATE A  DATE B
3   15/05/06    17/04/06
5   14/11/05    1/12/05
8   25/11/08    13/11/08
1   16/12/10    26/11/10
1   5/01/12     12/11/11
1   24/07/14    8/08/14
```

Comment: I'm closing as dupe of one of your older questions as the accepted answer fits perfectly with just a slight adjustement (`dfb[dfa, on=.(ID, Date), roll="nearest", mult="first", nomatch=0L][, .SD, .SDcols=c("ID", "DATEA", "DATEB")]` once your dataframes converted to data.tables and the Date properly defined.

Comment: @Cath Thank you Cath. I have first used this answer provided by David Arunberg      # Create range columns
    dfa[, c("Date_m_180", "Date_p_180") := .(Date - 180L, Date + 180L)]

    # Join away
    indx <- dfb[dfa, 
                on = .(ID, Date >= Date_m_180, Date <= Date_p_180), 
                which = TRUE, 
                mult = "first",
                nomatch = 0L]
    dfb[indx]

Comment: Thank you Cath. I have first used this answer provided by @David Arunberg  indx <- dfb[dfa, on = .(ID, Date >= Date_m_180, Date <= Date_p_180), which = TRUE, mult = "first",nomatch = 0L]
dfb[indx] However, this results in a list of multiple date B's that are within +/-180 days of Date A but not the nearest. When use this new data table created and I run your code I receive a nice list of the closest matches between Date A and Date B, but it does not remove those that are >180 days apart. I am trying to work out how I can combine both codes.  Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: typo @David Arenburg

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a way to use both roll= 180 and roll="nearest" together

Comment: I have solved this by using Cath's code first to select the nearest date combinations first. Then doing a simple diff column to calculate the difference between the dates and removing those >180 days. Thank you @Cath for your help with the code.

Answer (score 1):

An idea is to merge on `ID`, subtract the dadtes and keep the minimum, i.e.

```
d1 <- transform(merge(df1, df2, by = 'ID'), 
                 diff1 = as.POSIXct(DATE_A, '%d/%m/%y') - as.POSIXct(DATE_B, '%d/%m/%y'))

do.call(rbind, by(d1, d1$ID, function(i) i[which.min(i$diff1), ] ))
```

which gives,

> ```
>   ID   DATE_A   DATE_B      diff1
> 3  3 15/05/06 17/04/06  -701 days
> 5  5 14/11/05 26/09/05 -4322 days
> 8  8 25/11/08 31/03/09 -1947 days
> ```

Comment: thank you@Sotos. I am getting an error which may be because my dataframes are very large.

Comment: what's the error?

Comment: Error in vecseq(f__, len__, if (allow.cartesian || notjoin || !anyDuplicated(f__,  : 
  Join results in 27706 rows; more than 13904 = nrow(x)+nrow(i).Check for duplicate key values in i each of which join to the same group in x over and over again. If that's ok, try by=.EACHI to run j for each group to avoid the large allocation. If you are sure you wish to proceed, rerun with allow.cartesian=TRUE. Otherwise, please search for this error message in the FAQ, Wiki, Stack Overflow and datatable-help for advice.

Comment: @sar your error message comes from `data.table`, there was no clue in your question that you are working with this package (btw, the problem does not come from a too large dataframe, it is a matter of duplicated values)

Comment: apologies @Cath I will update my question